# Invoke isn't delaying?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, invoke

Here is the target code with the `Invoke` call:
[image]

Here is the player code:
[image]

I have also tried without the `nameof` statement but it doesnt work.

Comment: If you look in the Inspector window, what value do you have for “Finish Delay”? If you’ve had that ever set to, say, 0, then even putting 2 in the code isn’t going to help. The Inspector value will override your code value (because of the data being deserialised after loading).

Comment: Does the player have collision?

Comment: Do NOT post codes as screenshots!

Comment: What "Invoke"?  All I see/may not see are images.  What is the expected behaviour? [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Invoke()` you can use [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) to create some delay like the following:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.tag == "Player")
    {
       StartCoroutine(ReloadScene());
    }
}

IEnumerator ReloadScene()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(FinishDelay);
    SceneManager.ReloadScene(0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

make sure all the changes are synced with unity, click on the script in unity and see if the preview is the same as in VS. if it isn't just reopen unity.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).